# Bootstrap navbar text turns black after i click on it but only until i click to another element on the page

Tags: colors, navbar

I'm encountering an issue with the Bootstrap navbar in my code. When I click an element to navigate to another page and then return, the text color of the previously clicked link changes to black and remains so until I click somewhere else on the website. Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Any insights on what might be causing this and how I can resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

**This is the CSS code:**

`.nav-link { color: rgb(169, 181, 204); font-size: 0.98rem; }`

`a.nav-link:hover{ color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold;}`

It works perfectly but after i click on it and then come back, it remains black for some reason that i can't identify.

Comment: Could it be the:visited pseudoclass being applied?

Comment: I thought about it too, but it's not that :( It disappears as soon as I click on something else on the page. It's weird, it never happened before...

Comment: Might be :focus then, since you clicked on it, the control has focus and probably retains that focus when you navigate back. You can debug an element in the developer tools in any chromium browser